# Can I make a relation between 2 association class in UML?

Tags: database, associations, uml

Hey I have to make a modelization of a database handling seminars and booking, 
the question is : is it possible to use an association class (Evenement) to make another association class (Reservation) ?

If yes is it OK to have a composite primary key in reservation that exceed 3 attributes (ps: Salle is a composite key of 2 attributes) ?

You can see the class diagram here :

[image: class diagram]

Comment: Sure, why not? If that's what the model needs.

Comment: Why would you think it should not be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Association class is at the same time (simultaneously) an association and a class. So it has all the attributes and capabilities of a class.